# OneDrive error: Uploading is paused, Sign in to continue

Tags: onedrive

Why do I encounter an error, "Uploading is paused, Sign in to continue" after uploading a large file (~100MB) to onedrive?

Comment: Have you been moving about, weakening your signal? Loss of signal? If this is wifi, have you moved into another wifi range?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution from [here](http://boardreader.com/thread/Camera_Backup_is_Paused_on_4_0_5bwv3t__523f773d-8aae-4a51-b5f8-5fa1d007b829.html). Apparently, you should not allow your phone to lock when uploading.

> the app must be running in the background for the upload to continuously take place, which is why the uploading is paused when the mobile device is locked.